# Issue in suggestion dropdown of textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

The below page is a bottom sheet which has a text field and and list view below which is supposed to display the relevant tags based on what is typed in the text field.

```
class TagSelectorSheet extends StatefulWidget {

  double height;
  double width;
  int selectedTagIndex;

  TagSelectorSheet({@required this.width,@required this.height,@required this.selectedTagIndex});


  @override
  _TagSelectorSheetState createState() => _TagSelectorSheetState(this.height,this.width,this.selectedTagIndex);
}

class _TagSelectorSheetState extends State<TagSelectorSheet> {

  double height;
  double width;
  int selectedTagIndex;

  TextEditingController _tagSearch = TextEditingController();

  List _tags = List<String>();
  List _tagTileList = List<Widget>();

  _TagSelectorSheetState(this.height,this.width,this.selectedTagIndex);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _tags = ["Man","Child","ManChild","Phone","Watch","Phone","Life","Money","Something with long text"];
    for(int i=0;i<_tags.length;i++){
      _tagTileList.add(tagTile(_tags[i], selectedTagIndex));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: height * 0.025),
            child: Container(
              height: height * 0.075,
              width: width * 0.95,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _tagSearch,
                onChanged: _onChanged,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(height * 0.075 / 3.5),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.grey[700],),
                  hintText: "Search for a tag",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(thickness: 2,color: Colors.grey[400],),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: _tagTileList,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget tagTile(String tag,int index){
    return InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.pop(context,TagData(tag: tag,index: index));
     },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.05),
        width: width,
        height: height * 0.08,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border : Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.grey[400])),
        ),
        child: Align(alignment : Alignment.centerLeft,child: Text(tag,style: TextStyle(color: CustomColor.blue),)),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onChanged(String input)
  {
    setState(() {
      _tagTileList.clear();
      if(input.length == 0)
      {
        _tags.forEach((tag){_tagTileList.add(tagTile(tag,selectedTagIndex));});
      }
      else
      {
        _tags.forEach((tag) {
          if(tag.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
            _tagTileList.add(tagTile(tag,selectedTagIndex));
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

}
```

The goal is to display the tags which contains what is typed in the text field. Now I have implemented this in the above code and it's kind of working the way I want .

When I print the contents of '_tagTileList' at start of build function...... It works properly ( If I typed "man" in the field its shows two elements present in the '_tagTileList' which are "man" and "manChild".)

The issue is that even if its reflected correctly in the print statement. It still shows completely filled '_tagTileList' while displaying. (No matter what I type, the _tagTileList' is displayed with all tags as it was initialized in initstate).

Thanks in advance for the help.